# Sum of squares using lambda functions

Tags: python, lambda

I am thinking of different ways to take the sum of squares in python. I have found that the following works using list comprehensions:

```
def sum_of_squares(n):
    return sum(x ** 2 for x in range(1, n))
```

But, when using lambda functions, the following does not compute:

```
def sum_of_squares_lambda(n):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x**2 + y**2, range(1, n))
```

Why is this?

Comment: what do you mean by "does not compute"?

Comment: Because the sum of squares corresponds to `lambda x, y: x + y**2`, not `lambda x, y: x**2 + y**2`.

Comment: x + y**2 instead. x is the current sum in the lambda, so don't square it again.

Comment: It does not throw an error but the program runs forever on relatively small input. Size n >=100.

Comment: Not if you code it correctly.  Since your current implementation is squaring the running total it grows large quickly and takes a lot more computation time.

Answer (score 2):

Think about what `reduce` does.  It takes the output of one call and uses it as the first argument when calling the same function again.  So imagine n is 4.  Suppose you call your lambda `f`.  Then you are doing `f(f(1, 2), 3)`.  That is equivalent to:

```
(1**2 + 2**2)**2 + 3**2
```

Because the first argument to your lambda is squared, your first sum of squares will be squared again on the next call, and then that sum will be squared again on the next, and so on.

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot of sense. So it's almost like a recursive call on the next two elements of the iterable.

Answer (score 1):

You're only supposed to square each successive element. `x**2 + y**2` squares the running total (`x`) as well as each successive element (`y`). Change that to `x + y**2` and you'll get the correct result. Note that, as mentioned in comments, this requires a proper initial value as well, so you should pass `0` as the optional third argument.

```
>>> sum(x ** 2 for x in range(5,15))
985
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x + y**2, range(5,15))
965
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x + y**2, range(5,15), 0)
985
```

Comment: Using `x + y**2` will work as long as the sequence starts at 1, but it will fail if you try to extend it to arbitrary sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you plug in 4:

```
1^2 + 2^2 = 5 (you then take this result and put it back in the lambda)
5^2 + 3^2  = 34 (for reference the correct answer is 14)
```

It squares the "previous" sum as well in the `lambda`.

(You also have an off by one issue, it should be `n+1` in your range calls.)

Answer (score -2):

(for python 3 users)

```
from functools import reduce
```

To be able to use `reduce`.

Second, your function `sum_of_squares_lambda` won't work the way you expect it to because `reduce` will take twice (instead of once) every argument except the first and the last one.

Comment: If I hadn't imported reduce correctly then it would've thrown an error at runtime instead of taking a long time to compute.

Comment: `reduce` moved to `functools` in Python 3.  In Python 2 it is a built-in.

Comment: @math2001 What does that have to do with anything? Your answer initially read as "this won't work unless ....". Given that the main part of this answer is an assumption I think most Python users are capable of making, I don't find it very useful.